# Edit message with VideoNote in Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

How can I edit VideoNote message and change old video note to another one in Telebot? I guess I need edit_message_media method, but I don't understand how to use it for video notes.

I've tried to do it this way:

```
bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id,
                       media=types.VideoNote(open("video.mp4", "rb")))
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is impossible as for now (`December 2022`).

[Telegram API has](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#updating-messages) these methods for updating messages: `editMessageText`, `editMessageCaption`, `editMessageMedia`, `editMessageReplyMarkup`, `stopPoll`, `deleteMessage`,

The closest one is [`editMessageMedia`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#editmessagemedia) but it expects [`InputMedia`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#inputmedia) which in turn should be one of `InputMediaAnimation`, `InputMediaDocument`, `InputMediaAudio`, `InputMediaPhoto`, `InputMediaVideo`, but not [`VideoNote`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#videonote)

Also, I tried editing this kind of message using the official Android and Windows clients but didn't find such an option.
I assume Telegram doesn't have this option at all.